# nuxt3 で nuxt アプリケーション全体にemitするための方法

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js

nuxt2 から nuxt3 に移行しています。
下記のコードを nuxt3 に移行するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

```
<script lang="ts">
async someFnc() {
 await this.$nuxt.$emit("hoge/fuga")
 // someImpl
}
</script>
```

off するための実装は下記です。
pages/sample2.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
beforeDestroy():void {
 this.$nuxt.$off("hoge/fuga")
}
</script>
```

---

追記
下記のようなコードは

```
<script lang="ts">
async someFnc() {
 this.$emit('hoge')
}
</script>
```

このように移行できました。しかし、上記のコードは「アプリケーション全体」への発行のため、違うアプローチが必要だと考えています。

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const emit = defineEmit(['hoge'])
const someFnc = () => {
 emit('hoge')
}
</script>
```